# Keep getting an error because getElementById returns null

Tags: javascript

So, I'm trying to position a div with JavaScript, but when I do, I get the error "Uncaught: TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null".
I then decided to try window.onLoad, because maybe the page wasn't fully loaded, but I still get the error.

To make it clear, I know that getElementById returns null, I'm now just searching for a solution.

The HTML code:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="sjuku"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript code:

```
var square = document.getElementById("sjuku");

window.onload = function() {
    square.style.top = 100 + "px";
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is running before the `body` is encountered so at that point, the element doesn't exist and your `document.getElementById("sjuku")` line fails. Move your script to just before the closing `body` tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="sjuku"></div>
    
    <script src="main.js"></script>    
 </body>
</html>
```

And, by doing that, you really don't even need an `onload` event handler (unless you need to wait for external resources, like images, to finish loading) because by the time the parser gets to that location, all of the `body` HTML will have been parsed into memory and you save the need to wire up an event handler:

Also, if you know you want the `top` at `100px`, just write:

```
square.style.top = "100px";
```

So, your JavaScript in main.js can just be:

```
document.getElementById("sjuku").style.top = "100px";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you keep your script tag in the head element you can use the defer attribute

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="main.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
```

The defer attribute specifies that the script is executed when the page has finished parsing. Heads up though, this only works for external scripts.